# UDP Broadcast doesn't fire

Tags: vb.net, udp, broadcast

I'm trying to send a UDP broadcast but I do not see the packet on Wireshark.
My PC network adapter has 1.1.2.1.

```
Dim L_UDP_Client As UdpClient = New UdpClient(13690)
Dim L_Buffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GTIP")
L_UDP_Client.Send(L_Buffer, L_Buffer.Length, "255.255.255.255", 13699)
```

It works if I send

```
L_UDP_Client.Send(L_Buffer, L_Buffer.Length, "1.1.2.255", 13699)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojGSV.png)